# Complex logical test on drag to test dragged item against dropzone attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic, conditional-statements

I have a list of divs in a container.  I already have dragula set up and working.  Each of these divs has data attributes: data-age, data-gender, data-grade.  Not all divs will have all the attributes.

```
<div data-personaliasid="f193edc1-8f54-474b-bdd6-8c2fe2536513" data-
fullname="Sophie Kurtis" data-name="Kurtis" data-age="10" data-
gender="2" data-grade="6" class="well persondiv" style="margin-
bottom:2px; padding:5px;">...</div>
```

For Drop zones I have divs that also have some/all/none of the following data attributes: `data-gender`, `data-gradestart`, `data-gradend`, `data-agestart`, `data-ageend`.

```
<div class="dragula-container memberlist panel-body" id="48aa8cfd-264d-
4d40-9550-e8741c1b3d41" style="min-height: 100px;" data-gender="1" 
data-gradestart="12" data-gradeend="10" data-agestart="" data-
ageend="">...</div>
```

Because the items and the drop zone are created dynamically, I can't say if every data attribute will always be present on the person or the memberlist drop zone.

I am trying to create an `.on('drag',function(source){})` that will set up tests with the filters present on the group and run the matching person data attributes through the test and fail if any of them fails.

```
persondiv data-gender == memberslist data-gender 
persondiv data-age between memberslist data-agestart and data-ageend
persondiv data-grade(number) between memberslist data-gradestart and data-gradeend
```

Unfortunately I can't wrap my head around this to know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I was able to come up with, but its checking the variables for each group and they should be before the .each() function and only called once.  Everything starts with the class on and gets removed as each test is failed.  I don't know if this is the best way, but it works.

```
    .on('drag', function(el){
    $('.memberlist').each(function (){
        var persongender = $(el).attr("data-gender"); 
        var personage = $(el).attr("data-age");
        var persongrade = $(el).attr("data-grade");
        var testpassed = 'yes'


        //Gender Filter Test
        if(testpassed == 'yes' && $(this).data('gender') !== undefined && $(this).data('gender') !== null) {
            if(persongender == $(this).data('gender')){
                $(this).addClass("dragzone",100);
                }
            else { 
                $(this).removeClass("dragzone",1);
                testpassed = 'no';
            }
            }
        //Age Filter Test
        if(testpassed == 'yes' && $(this).data('agestart') !== undefined && $(this).data('agestart') !== null) {
            if ($(this).data('agestart') <= personage && personage <= $(this).data('ageend')) {
                $(this).addClass("dragzone",100);
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("dragzone",1);
                testpassed = 'no';
            }
        }
        //Grade Filter Test
        if(testpassed == 'yes' && $(this).data('gradestart') !== undefined && $(this).data('gradeend') !== null && $(this).data('gradeend') !== undefined && $(this).data('gradeend') !== null) {
            if ($(this).data('gradeend') <= persongrade && persongrade <= $(this).data('gradestart')) {
                $(this).addClass("dragzone",100);
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("dragzone",1);
                testpassed = 'no';
            }
        }
    });
});
```